# Change android screen orientation from code

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I want my application to be able to get the current screen orientation and change it to landscape/portrait. Which things do I need to declare in the manifest file to deal with screen orientation ?

Comment: If you don't set any property in manifest for landscape/portrait. Your device decides which you need depends on your device orientation. but didn't understand what you actually want. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have said that my application deal with screen orientation, and I want to know which permission, activity or whatever that are needed to be declared in manifest file

Comment: @user6281889 from what i can understand you want to change the orientation of your app from code. If this is what you want then please check my answer and update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the orientation to Landscape:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

If you want to set the orientation to Portrait:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Also add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest to avoid reloading the activity on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the orientation u can use:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

---

And for setting the orientation:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

Comment: I want to get a boolean variable "portrait" to use in another method: 

 private void checkScreenOrientation()
  {
     int screenOrientation= Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (screenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
      portrait = true;
    }
    else
    {
      portrait = false;
    }
  }

The compiler said that "There is no such available reference" and there was a red line under getResources(). 

Do you know what is incorrect ?

Comment: getResources is non static method so u can't use Activity.getResources() simply use getResources inside an activity

Comment: Do you have an email ? Then would you mind giving me your email and I can discuss something ?